# Issue in Quartz rescheduling

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have an issue with Quartz job rescheduling. The issue is as below,

1. I have 2 Scheduler jobs which are based on Cron expressions.
2. The first job (Job A )will configure the second job (Job B)and Job A itself based on cron expressions provided in data base table.
3. The Job A is configured to run at every 0th minute of hour and Job B is scheduled to run at 15th minute of every hour.
4. After both the jobs ran for first time , I am changing the cron expression for the Job B to 'run it on every 45th minute of every hour'
5. On the 0th minute of next hour, Job A is reconfiguring Job B melodramatically (Using Scheduler.rescheduleJob()). At this point expected behavior is
   the Job B should run on next 45th minute of the coming hour. But the Job b is running along with the Job A running on 0th miute of the hour and on
   45th minute as expected. Later on it is running on 45th minute only as expected.

Additional information:
Quartz version used : 1.6.5
This scheduling program is deployed in Jboss 4.3 application server with two nodes in clustered environment
Database used : Oracle 10g

Could somebody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the existing trigger and adding it a-new on update, instead of rescheduling .